# How are unwanted ships always landing on planets in the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars

While I'm rewatching Clone Wars, there have been multiple times that one of the bad guys slowly parks a ship on a landing platform before starting trouble. I'm not talking about giant armadas - this is often a single ship (for example, Dooku landing on one of the Pike planets in s06e10).

Are there no planetary defense systems, shields, or even security ships? No early warning or radar? Some planets are pretty backwater like Florrum but this even happens on fairly advanced planets. I'd also imagine that some things like radar are relatively cheap in comparison to the cost of building structures, buying ships, etc. to settle on a planet.

Comment: You might want to reword your title to something such as *Why are ships not challenged from landing on planets in Star Wars?* It might want to note that not every planet had a [planetary defense force](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Planetary_defense_forces), there are a few examples though such as [Kerkoidia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kerkoidia). Think of it from the point of view of a planetary government, if there is no threat to your planet's security, then there is no need for a military/security force.

Comment: In RotJ, the rebels spoof their signals, iirc, similar things happen in the various cartoon series; transponder signals and such

Comment: Not to mention, if you keep a ship with as neutral of a reputation as possible, and make it look as non-threatening as possible, then you'd just look like another "average-joe" civilian coming in to land.

Answer (score 4):

Like @NKCambell said, spoofing or otherwise fooling the local security is usually the explanation in situations where it isn't full-on battleships.

There are systems like [BoSS](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bureau_of_Ships_and_Services) in place to try to keep track of ships, but usually our protagonists are just too good at evading capture.

In both the Endor and Scarif scene it is made clear that there are early warning systems, long distance scanning and access codes in place to try to stop unauthorized acccess to sensitive installations. Even Cloud City greets the Falcon with warning shots and escorts them to a landing platform, so it isn't alien to the galaxy.

Before the battle of Hoth, the rebels discover the imperial forces when [Admiral Ozzel came out of lightspeed too close to the system](https://youtu.be/aV2DLkDPwM8?t=25) so even the ragtag rebels seems to have given this some thought.

In most cases, Star Wars infiltration is a question of being inconspicuous, not present an immediate danger, landing on a backwater like Tatooine where security is nearly on-existant or simply being lost in the masses like at Coruscant.